# React.js acessing component props via e.target

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend

i want to access items desc's to add them to 'cart'.
exactly i would like to change hook value on Item click.
thanks for your time
some code here:

```
{items.map(
      item =>(
        <Item src={item.recipe.image} 
        desc = {item.recipe.label}
        price = {`${(item.recipe.label).length}$`} 

        />

      )
    )}
```

Comment: if is there not enough code please just tell me

Comment: Please add more code and explain a little more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the value in `desc` as an argument to the `onClick` function rather than trying to hack the value of an attribute/prop

```
{items.map(
      item =>(
        <Item src={item.recipe.image} 
        desc = {item.recipe.label}
        price = {`${(item.recipe.label).length}$`} 
        onClick = {(e) => handleClick(e,item.recipe.label)}
        />
      )
    )}
```

and on the `handleClick` function get the second argument as the `desc`

Comment: i had mostly same code as yours but with little syntax error, thanks anyway.